# websockets workerman

Tags: nginx, websocket, workerman

Не получается запустить сокет на `http` на доменном имени, работает только на `IP`

```
$tcp_worker = new Worker('websocket://15.15.15.15:2222'); //В таком виде работает

$tcp_worker = new Worker('websocket://mydomain.com:2222'); //В таком виде не работает
```

Реально ли это или доменное имя только на SSL работает?

Ошибка: `Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: А домен ведет куда нужно или как? А какие настройки у Nginx?

Comment: сам домен работает, таймаутит только сокет по доменному имени

а вот как настроить nginx для этого дела, пока не нашел

в самом nginx для сокета ничего не прописывал, кроме

worker_processes auto;
events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

Answer (score 1):

1. нет, "доменное имя только на SSL работает" - это неправильное утверждение.

Дело в том, что DNS (система доменных имен, отвечающая за буквенные имена) это штука, совершенно отдельная от HTTP и SSL. (ну, SSL применяется в основном на HTTP, но, вообще говоря, им не ограничивается)

Применительно к вебсокетам - SSL влияет на префикс в URL ( ws или wss )

2. Почему же не работает?

Проверяйте разрешение имен. Что у Вас mydomain.com означает именно тот IP адрес, на котором вебсокет работает.

делается это примерно так:

```
    > nslookup
    Default Server:  UnKnown
    Address:  192.168.10.250

    > it.junecat.ru
    Server:  UnKnown
    Address:  192.168.10.250

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:    it.junecat.ru
    Address:  77.246.237.74
```

Когда проверяете - не забудьте, что для локальной машины обычно файл hosts имеет приоритет над DNS - разрешением имен. Надо проверить, что там не прописано что то, что сбивает вашу программу с толку.

Если всё это не помогло - можно вооружиться fiddler'ом или wireshark'ом и посмотреть, в одно и то же место пытается программа пойти, или нет? просто сравнив трафик при этих попытках коннекта

Можно еще один фокус провернуть. Если не работает то, что Вы вписали в конфиг nginx'а - попробуйте mydomain.com вписать в какую то очень простую строчку конфига, типа proxy_redirect. Если редирект заработает - значит, с разрешением имен все хорошо.

И еще, что nginx пговорит на команду `sudo nginx -t` - это проверка корректности конфига?

**Ддополнение**

Я написал маленькое дополнение после такого учтонения:

"сам сокет запущен через PHP, а обращения идут с клиента(ноды) по локалке"

Смотрите.

Теперь я полностью потерял нить рассуждений.

вернемся к началу вопроса:

`$tcp_worker = new Worker('websocket://15.15.15.15:2222'); //В таком виде работает`

`$tcp_worker = new Worker('websocket://mydomain.com:2222'); //В таком виде не работает`

Вопрос: а в каком месте этот код написан?

я ожидаю вот чего.

У вас есть сервер. Несмотря на все попытки скрыть это, стало понятно, что сервер, скорее всего - это nginx + php-fpm

Затем, у Вас на сервере есть что то, что создаёт серверный web-socket. Этот код нигде в вопросе не написан. Вероятно, это какой то код на php. Причем, опять таки, непонятно, как этот код запущен в режиме сервиса: ведь для того, чтобы клиент мог подключиться к сокету - сервер должен слушать. А все технологии запуска php под nginx - рассчитаны на "дёрнули - отработал - умер!", то есть ни о каких долгоживущих процессах там вроде как речи не идёт.

И наконец, у вас должно быть что то, что пытается с склиента к этому серверному сокету обратиться. И ТОЛЬКО В ЭТОМ МЕСТЕ у вас вообще возникает доменное имя. Или ip. Во всех остальных местах сокет (по умолчанию, если не приложить дополнительных усилий) биндится к IP 0.0.0.0 - то есть, к любому доступному интерфейсу.

Comment: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful


nginx -t выдает так, с этим все ок


не нашел никакой документации к сожалению для настройки ws и wss на стороне веб-сервера либо в DNS

Comment: А какая исходная задача? что надо сделать с nginx? Можно своими словами рассказать, как всё должно работать?

Comment: мне нужно запустить вебсокет на https, чтобы к нему могли подключаться клиенты с различных источников, в принципе дефолтная задача для сокета

т.к. работает по ИП сокет, в нем конкретно проблемы не вижу, поэтому решил решать проблему постепенно, начиная с настройки работы сокета на доменном имени, для начала без ssl

если есть рабочие конфиги nginx + если есть какие-то строгие правила для hosts, был бы благодарен за рабочий пример

Comment: Веб сервер какой? nginx - это Ваш веб - сервер? Он же, вроде, только статику кеширует...

Comment: веб сервер да, nginx, легких путей не ищем , apache не используется вообще

Comment: ну, у нас нет предвзятого отношения в nginx, я, скорее, восхищаюсь nginx. Но обычно всякие чаты с использованием вебсокета пишут на ноде, и умещают в 10-12 строк (это с комментариями). Есть много инфы по проксированию веб-сокетов в nginx. но - и Вы меня можете сейчас смело послать (читать документацию) я не представляю, как nginx может выступать веб-сервером, на котором есть server side. Можно хоть какой то пример такого посмотреть?

Comment: Кажется, я нашел инфу о том, как программировать под nginx: https://habr.com/ru/post/267955/. Диалект джаваскрипта, называется энджинкс скрипт. Но это о-о-о-о-чень сурово.

Comment: сам сокет запущен через PHP, а обращения идут с клиента(ноды) по локалке